# How to search for a link?

Tags: support, search

Yesterday I got the "Announcer" badge for having shared this link: 
`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367140/insert-figures-for-a-subsection-and-start-another-subsection-after-image`.

How can I find the place where I shared it?

Simply searching for the link or part of it doesn't work.

Comment: I've had a similar, but even more puzzling experience, and I've posted this question on the main meta site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328522/169475

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Where you shared it

I think it is [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370627/why-should-the-h-option-not-be-used-in-floats#comment915324_370627):

> @StevenB.Segletes I know it (see the first words of this answer of mine: tex.stackexchange.com/a/367156/101651), I'd like to have an expert answer about the topic that can be linked every time one have to explain it to a new user. – CarLaTeX May 19 '17 at 19:05

---

### How I found it

#### What is the link?

To get the Announcer badge, there must be a link which has got more than 25 views (from 25 different IP addresses, of course) *which ends by your UserID* ([101651](/users/101651)).

The linked question has three posts which can give you such a link:

- The question itself, it will give you [`https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367140/101651`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367140)
- Stephen Mason's answer, it will give you [`https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367141/101651`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367141)
- Your answer, it will give you [`https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367156/101651`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367156)

Of those links, I think you must have got the badge for the link to your answer (the last listed above). So I only searched for that link and ignore the others, however you may try to find the other links.

#### Search for the link inside questions and answers

I used the search filter of Stack Exchange and I found nothing.

#### Search for the link inside comments (but also Qs and As as well)

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367156/101651+site:tex.stackexchange.com&filter=0&biw=1366&bih=667) points me to only two posts

- Your answer (of course we won't find it in your answer).
- [Why should the "H" option not be used in floats?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370627/156344).

Now it is easy. Just read your questions and comments there, move the cursor to every link inside them, and check if the link is `https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367156/101651`. And I found the linked comment as the first result. (I `return 0;` right after that, but you may continue searching there.)